# Average not working with indirect formula and blank values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have this formula:

```
=IFERROR(
(
(
IFERROR(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$15");"")
+IFERROR(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$29");"")
+IFERROR(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$43");"")
+IFERROR(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$57");"")
+IFERROR(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$71");"")
+IFERROR(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$84");"")
)
/6);"")
```

When any of these IDIRECTS return a blank value, I get an #VALUE! error (without the first IFERROR). Each individual line works just fine, and when putting them in cells individually, I can average them fine. If I remove the /6 part of this formula however, and wrap the lines with an AVERAGE-formula, I get the #VALUE! error also.

How can I proceed?

**EDIT, SOLUTION FOUND (Thanks Mrig)**:

```
=IFERROR(
(
(
IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$15"));INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$15");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$29"));INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$29");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$43"));INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$43");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$57"));INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$57");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$71"));INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$71");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$84"));INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$84");0)
)/
(
COUNTIF(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$15");">=0")
+COUNTIF(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$29");">=0")
+COUNTIF(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$43");">=0")
+COUNTIF(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$57");">=0")
+COUNTIF(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$71");">=0")
+COUNTIF(INDIRECT($A7&"!$E$82");">=0")
)
);"")
```

The COUNTIF's bascially replaces the number "6" in the original code, and checks which of the INSNUMER's (instead of IFERROR's) that isn't blanks, so anything that's 0% or higher (actual value) will be counted, to get to the true average.

Comment: Instead of `""` try returning `0` on the inner errors

Comment: Also make sure you do not have text in any of cells you are referencing with indirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the suggestions above in the comments, you can use `IF(ISNUMBER())` instead of `IFERROR()`

```
=IFERROR(
(
(
IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$15"));INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$15");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$29"));INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$29");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$43"));INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$43");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$57"));INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$57");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$71"));INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$71");0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$84"));INDIRECT($A6&"!$E$84");0)
)/6);"")
```

Comment: Thank you! This kinda works, though I had to find a way to make 6 into whatever number of ISNUMER's that wasn't blanks, but rather 0% or higher. Posting final code in original post.

Answer (score 3):

I started off thinking that your 'stagger' was 14 rows so I went with this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(E15:E84), 14)=1, IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A6&"!E15:E84")), INDIRECT($A6&"!E15:E84"))))
```

... but your 'stagger' is not a consistent 14 rows; the last gap is 13 rows so I modified it to this:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ROW(15:84)={15,29,43,57,71,84}, IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A6&"!E15:E84")), INDIRECT($A6&"!E15:E84"))))
```

That produces a true average without zero substitution on blank cells while discarding text values.